# VBA Runtime Error 1004 - Unable to Paste a range as a picture on another tab

Tags: excel, vba, string, runtime-error

I've been running into multiple runtime error issues when running my code. The code goes through different ranges of data and formats them appropriately on tab "Inputs". At this point, the vba code copies the range (R12) in this example and attempts to paste that range as a picture on tab "Print". However, I created a string (S12) on the "Inputs" tab that contains the cell location of where this picture will be pasted on the "Print" tab.

Before, I used multiple Select commands which slowed the macro down considerably and still would result with multiple run time errors. Could someone look at the following code and help me determine a better way for the code to copy the range of cells, read the cell location from the string, and paste the picture at that location on the "Print" tab?

Thank you!

Code:

```
Dim RC12 As Range
 If Not (Sheets("Input").Range("KT167").Value) = "" Then
  Set RC12 = Sheets("Input").Range("DV164:EC171")
  RC12.CopyPicture
    Else:
     Set RC12 = Sheets("Input").Range("DW164:EC171")
     RC12.CopyPicture
        End If

Dim S12 As String
S12 = Sheets("Input").Range("KV167").Value
Sheets("Print").Range(S12).PasteSpecial
Sheets("Print").Pictures(Sheets("Print").Pictures.Count).Name = "Rate12"


Dim R12 As Shape
Set R12 = Sheets("Print").Shapes("Rate12")
R12.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
 If (Sheets("Input").Range("KS167").Value) = "" Then
  R12.Height = 156.96
  R12.Width = 670.32
    Else:
      If (Sheets("Input").Range("KT167").Value) = "" Then
       R12.Height = 156.96
       R12.Width = 197.28
        Else:
         R12.Height = 156.96
         R12.Width = 264.24
           End If
              End If
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I organized the code for better understanding, putting the DIMs at the top of the code. The only flaw I noticed was when you referred to Range("S12") .PasteSpecial without the parentheses. Ah... I named the code as 'fnCodeToPrintCellsAsImage', as you can see:

```
Option Explicit

Sub fnCodeToPrintCellsAsImage()
    Dim RC12 As Range
    Dim S12 As String
    Dim R12 As Shape

    If Not (Sheets("Input").Range("KT167").Value) = "" Then
        Set RC12 = Sheets("Input").Range("DV164:EC171")
        RC12.CopyPicture
Else:
        Set RC12 = Sheets("Input").Range("DW164:EC171")
        RC12.CopyPicture
    End If
    
    S12 = Sheets("Input").Range("KV167").Value
    Sheets("Print").Range("S12").PasteSpecial
    Sheets("Print").Pictures(Sheets("Print").Pictures.Count).Name = "Rate12"

    Set R12 = Sheets("Print").Shapes("Rate12")
    R12.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    If (Sheets("Input").Range("KS167").Value) = "" Then
        R12.Height = 156.96
        R12.Width = 670.32
    Else
        If (Sheets("Input").Range("KT167").Value) = "" Then
            R12.Height = 156.96
            R12.Width = 197.28
        Else
            R12.Height = 156.96
            R12.Width = 264.24
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Alexcel. I don't think I'd add the parentheses as I want it to reference the string S12 and not the cell. I've discovered that my issue appeared to be that excel was too slow in completing the prior command before moving on. The run-time error appeared to be from the clipboard not having copied the picture before attempting to paste. While inefficient, I have added the line "Application.Wait" for 1 second between the copy and paste. This seems to have fixed my issues. If there's anyone that knows a more efficient way of fixing this issue, that would be greatly appreciated.